# Google Maps Search: Center map on search results markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map (v3) setup with search functionality to search a Fusion Table.  The search works fine, but I need for the map to center on the search results marker(s).  I have a large field of markers and would like for the user to see all of the search results in one screen.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Fusion Tables v1.0 API or GViz to query the table. Add all the locations to a google.maps.LatLngBounds object (with extend).  Call the .fitBounds method of your map object on the resulting bounds.  Need more information to give more details than that.

Examples querying tables with various data formats on [geocodezip.com](http://www.geocodezip.com)

Comment: Thank you so much, this sounds like exactly the architecture to use.  I can't seem to find a way to add all of the locations from the Fusion Table query into the google.maps.LatLngBounds object, however.  I don't see how I could iterate the Fusion Table query to accomplish this.  Here is the code I have so far:  Layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: "'col3'",
                from: TableID
            },
            styleId: 2,
            templateId: 2
        });

Comment: Please update your question with code. It is really hard to read in the comments.  And it would be helpful to include a reference to your FusionTable also as each of these queries needs to be tailored to the table being queried.

Comment: I figured it out using this example for base code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434685/determine-center-bounding-box-of-fusiontableslayer-in-google-maps-api  Basically, there are 2 queries to the Fusion table: one to find the markers and one to generate the bounds.  Thanks again!